# Stand alone dividend contract that pays out different token

Tags: solidity, shares

I'm trying to create a dividend contract that contains a balance of token A which should be divided among holders of token B in proportion to their current balance. Both of these tokens are already deployed and I can't augment either of their transfer() functions.

The total amount to be shared can be increased at any time by the owner sending an amount of token A to the contract. Of course it is not an option to iterate through all token B holders upon this deposit due to gas issues.

Is it possible to create an accurate dividend contract like this without changing the already deployed token contracts? Would I need to create an offchain airdrop style script to distribute these dividends instead?

```
//Currently have something like this, but it isn't accurate
 function getDistributableAmount() public view returns(uint) {
        uint tokenAmount = TOKENB.tokenBalances(msg.sender);
        uint totalBSupply = TOKENB.totalAmount();

        uint totalAmount = TOKENA.balanceOf(this);

        return totalAmount.mul(totalBSupply).div(totalAmount);
    }
```

Comment: Yes to both of your questions (it is possible, and you need to create an offchain airdrop). Please explain and/or give examples of why you think your contract isn't accurate.

Comment: The airdrop suggestion was a last resort, if I couldn't find a way to implement this. Basically the total amount can be increased any time and the holder can withdraw their dividends at anytime, the dividends aren't saved in the contract so need to be calculated upon withdrawal. Ideally the withdraw should be called automatically on transfer so that they don't lose any divs. Also, in that code example, if total is 1000 and 2 people have 50% each, first one would withdraw 500, second would withdraw 250, which is totally wrong.